# Django AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'set_password' but user is not override

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'set_password'
```

The problem is I didn't override the class User:

My model.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

My view.py:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        user = form.save(commit=False)
        print type(user)
        # Cleaning and normalizing data
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        # returns User objects if the credential are correct
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('website:home')
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

And this is my form.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                             'type': 'password',
                                                             'placeholder': 'Enter your password'}))
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
```

I don't really know also if I should override the User class. In which case I should and in which case I shouldn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inherit from `AbstractUser` to get access to `set_password` attribute. Instead of using `models.Model` use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
```

Your `User` model is not the same as django's `User` model.

Reference [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: I did so but it generated the following problem: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'password' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'

Comment: This is because there is a field called password in AbstractUser.

Comment: Create a custom user model if you have authentication requirements that are different from those given by django itself

Comment: I just need a password. But I don't know if I should try to override the field or just rename it another way. And how to override just the password

Comment: If you want to gain more flexibility (override fields) then inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`

Answer (score 3):

from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
replace
**user.set_password(password)** by **user.password = make_password('password')**
it clear and work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The User model in Django has .set_password but if you made your own you should try OneToOneField(User) from there you just have to make sure you save both in the views.

```
user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
if user_form.is_valid():
    user = user_form.save()
    user.set_password(user.password)
    profile = user.userprofile
    profile.bio = request.POST['bio']
    profile.save()
```